# php - Delete a specific category when deleting a user

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I'm using the following function to create a portfolio category named "tips_username" when a user registers on my Wordpress website.

```
add_action('user_register', 'auto_create_traveltip_category');
function auto_create_traveltip_category($user_id) {
    $tip_category_name = 'tips_' . $_POST['user_login'];
    wp_insert_term($tip_category_name, 'portfolio_entries', array(
            'description' => 'Travel Tip for ' . $_POST['user_login'],
            'slug'        => 'tips-' . $_POST['user_login'],
            'parent'      =>  '',
            )
    );
}
```

This is working fine, but now I need a function to automatically delete the category when I delete a user, for example from the user list. I implemented the following function taking inspiration from https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_user:

```
function delete_traveltip_category_with_user($user_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $user_obj = get_userdata($user_id);
    $tip_cat_name = 'tips_' . $user_obj->user_login;
    $tip_cat_desc = get_term_by('name', $tip_cat_name, 'portfolio_entries');
    $tip_cat_id = $tip_cat_desc->term_id;
    wp_delete_term( $tip_cat_id, 'portfolio_entries' );
}
add_action( 'delete_user', 'delete_traveltip_category_with_user' );
```

Unfortunately it is not working. Can you please have a look and tell me what's wrong with it? Thanks!!

Comment: Why don't you use this ? 
`<?php wp_delete_category( $cat_ID ) ?>`
Source : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_category

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Adrien! I tried to use `wp_delete_category( $cat_ID )` but it's still not working. I tried to `echo` the variable `$tip_cat_name` but I get only "tips_" so there must be something wrong in the first part of the code.

Comment: Have you check $user_id, by echo them , i think you may not get that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `user_id` argument is not set. You have to call the `do_action()` function to pass the `user_id` value to your function.

source : [do_action()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/)

**EDIT**
You have to call the `do_action()` function in your template (delete.php for example).

`do_action('delete_traveltip_category_with_user', $user_id)`

Where $user_id is the id to delete. It will call your custom function from the template.
Hope it helps.

Comment: get_current_user()  this will returns the current logged in user, but this is not useful here because here user is deleted.

Comment: Right! The current user is not set. Can you please tell me how exactly to use the `do_action` function to extract the user I'm going to delete? Should I write `do_action (get_userdata($user_id));` ?